# Python program that calculates the probability of getting 1 at least twice when rolling a fair die 12 times

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability

```
import random
import sys

bestcounter1 = 0
bestcounter2=0
get_sample = int(sys.argv[1])

for i in range(get_sample):
    for i in range(12):
        if (random.randint(1,6)==1):
            bestcounter1+=1
            bestcounter2+=1

oneatleasttwice = (bestcounter2*1.0)/(2*(get_sample))

#Divide by 2 to make both comparable. Otherwise 2 will always be greater than 1 !
print("One atleast twice in 12 rolls: ", oneatleasttwice)
```

Can anybody explain whether the logic used here is correct or not? The output I get is always around 1.

Thanks

Comment: This is correct over a large sample size but easily missed on such a small one: 12. I’d suggest you roll the die several thousand or tens of thousands of times and compare the number of times you saw each face.

Comment: Two `i`s are used in both outer and inner loop and it seems `bestcount1` is useless. Is your code correctly obtained?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're obliged to solve this via the sampling method but it would be far easier to compute it mathematically given that the outcome probabilities for a six-sided die is fixed. You may choose to take n as an argument for the number of rolls. Thereafter, the solution would just be 1 - (probability of 0x 1s) - (probability of 1x 1s).

p.s. If the answer that you got is close to one then it's probably incorrect, by the way. As a sanity check, there's an 11.2% chance that you get 0x 1s over 12 rolls.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place your counters on the right places. Suppose `bestcounter1` is used to count values of 1 during every run (12 rolls) while `bestcounter2` is used to count runs when you got 2 or more values of 1. Then your main for loop should look like this:

```
for i in range(get_sample):
    # reset before every run
    bestcounter1 = 0
    for i in range(12):
        if random.randint(1, 6) == 1:
            # count values of 1
            bestcounter1 += 1
        # check if we got 2 or more values of 1
        if bestcounter1 >= 2:
            # count proper cases
            bestcounter2 += 1
            break

oneatleasttwice = bestcounter2 / get_sample
```

I got result 61.9% with one million runs.

Comment: >while bestcounter2 is used to count runs when you got 2 or more values of 1.     Ah I see now! This part escaped me! Thanks a lot!